# Merge [dust] and [regolith]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, tag-synonyms, tagging

It seems to me that [dust](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dust) and [regolith](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regolith) are p̶e̶r̶f̶e̶c̶t̶
̶ more or less synonyms (for the purpose of this site). I suggest we merge and synonymize. What do you think? ("Yes" answers should specify which tag becomes the primary.)

Comment: FYI - I know cosmic dust is a different matter, but we already have a separate tag for that: [tag:space-dust]. The [tag:dust] tag has [tag:planetary-dust] as a synonym, indicating that it is intended to exclude cosmic dust.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree. Definition of [regolith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regolith):

> Regolith (/ˈrɛɡəlɪθ/)[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regolith) is a layer of loose, heterogeneous superficial deposits covering solid rock. It includes dust, *soil, broken rock, and other related materials*

(emphasis mine). Regolith is a superset of dust, so please don't treat them as synonyms.

Comment: Is the synonym mechanism strictly for synonyms, or does it also indicate when "a" is a subset of "b" by making "a" a synonym of "b"

Comment: @JCRM is correct the synonym mechanism is also intended for subset/superset relationships whenever one of the categories would be too small without the other. Of course, in those cases the subset should always merge into the superset, not the other way around. So it sounds like we should merge dust into regolith.

Comment: I edited the question to remove the word "perfect" and qualify what I meant by synonym.

Answer (score 0):

I propose we merge [dust](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dust) into [regolith](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regolith), per the discussion [here](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1201/merge-dust-and-regolith/1208#comment4575_1208) regarding subset/superset relationships.

Comment: I concur. I think this will make the site work better for users asking questions and/or finding answers. There is dust on bodies which is enough like regolith that they can share the same Stack Exchange tag, and there is space dust which is individual particles floating in space. `regolith` and `space-dust` should be sufficient for this site.