# Cleaning up the [dust]

Tags: discussion

When reading the question [Dealing with lunar regolith](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/40696/dealing-with-lunar-regolith) I looked at the [dust] tag and saw there's also a [space-dust] tag.

Reading the first level descriptions it sounds like [space-dust] is supposed to be, erm, dust floating in space, and [dust] is dust on planetary surfaces. Maybe? But the usage of the tags does not bear this out.

I was about to go on an tag edit rampage but decided to ask first if this was the true intent of the two tags.

Or should they be synonymized?

[dust] ==> used 38 times

> Questions regarding small, clustered pieces of dirt/rock, and it's
>   effect on space exploration.

[space-dust] ==> used 13 times

> Questions about Cosmic-dust which is a dust found in the cosmos,
>   capable of interacting with the electromagnetic radiation and they are
>   formed by supernovae, birth of star.

Comment: Related: https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1201/merge-dust-and-regolith

Answer (score 2):

In the related discussion linked in the comments, users previously rejected my proposal to make dust a synonym of regolith, even after I pointed out the existence of the space-dust tag and that subset tags can be synonymized to the superset. If we are going to maintain the existence of the dust tag, I agree with you that we need to make it more clear that it relates to planetary dust and what the distinction is between dust and regolith.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102882/discussion-on-answer-by-called2voyage-cleaning-up-the-dust).